# Linux hash.h : Using the fast hashing routine

Tags: c, linux, hash

How can we use hash.h in our code? I want to code a fast hash table which takes a double and spews out a pointer. Is it possible to use it. I dont see any of the usual routines associated with hashes in it.

Soham

Comment: This `hash.h`? http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/lxr/source/include/linux/hash.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like what you want is a *map-based data structure* that internally uses a hash function. `hash.h` only provides the latter, but there are libraries floating around that give you the data structure. An example using libHX (which is available in all major Linux distros) to map a double to a pointer (error handling left out for brevity), using a particular hash function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libHX/map.h>

static unsigned long linux_hash(const void *p, size_t chars)
{
        // replace return 0 by algorithm from hash.h
        return 0;
}

static const struct HXmap_ops ops = {
        .k_hash = linux_hash,
};

int main(void)
{
        struct HXmap *map;
        double i;

        map = HXmap_init5(HXMAPT_DEFAULT, HXMAP_CKEY, &ops, sizeof(double), 0);
        i = 3.141;
        HXmap_add(map, &i, main);
        i = 3.141/2;
        HXmap_add(map, &i, map);

        i = 3.141;
        printf("3.141 maps to %p\n", HXmap_get(map, &i));
        i = 3.141/2;
        printf("pi/2 maps to %p\n", HXmap_get(map, &i));
        return 0;
}
```

When no k_hash were specified, jenkins3 would be used as a reasonable default. The hash function from Linux's `hash.h` seems very minimal and may not provide as good properties.

Comment: Suuuweeeeeettt....what a brilliant piece of code.Now the crux of the question. Where can I read more about HXmap?

Comment: where isLibHX installed on Ubuntu10.10 Its there on Distro map for LibHX on sourceforge, but cant find it. Would appreciate the help

Comment: libhx-dev >= 3.0 is provided in Ubuntu's own repositories (just apt-get it). It is installed into the same place as other libraries (/usr/lib64 or /usr/lib, depending on arch). Furthermore, it also uses pkg-config, so the process for actually using it is pretty standardized.

Answer (score 0):

A hash will spit out a number, it will never spit out a pointer.

The number can be used to store and find the index of an item in an array (or similar structure) but it will have nothing to do with the item's actual memory address.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Edwin is it possible for any other data structure, to implement something like that. I want a (ideally) O(1) search for finding another data structure(say a structure)

Comment: He's talking about a hash *table* that maps doubles to pointers, whereas you are talking about a hash *value* as produced by a hash *function*.

Comment: @Soham, If you want O(1) search, a Hashtable is what you'll need.  The hashing function will spit out the index to the table, which is where you will store the pointer / object reference.  @Jim Thank you, you are correct in detailing how we both viewed the problem.